# For a group of n equally probable outcomes, how many ways can groups of n outcomes occur when each outcome is independent of previous selections?

Tags: probability, sampling, binary-data

Example:

I have 3 coinflips.  How do I calculate the probability of any possible outcome if I repeat the 3 flips many times?

There are 8 possible sequences for the 3 flips ranging from all heads to all tails and mixtures of heads and tails, all equally probable (1/8 for each - (1/2)^3).

I want to determine the probability of any combination of the 8 sequences.  Each sequence is independent of the previous coinflip sequences.

Let's label the 8 sequences 1,2,3, ...,8.  Is there a general formula that would enable me to calculate the probability of any possible combination of results for 8 consecutive 3 flip trials?

I know the probability for getting each one of the possible sequences once is 8!/8^8.

But what about the probability for 3 of any specific sequence and the other 5 from one each of the remaining 7 possibilities?

Probability for 3 of any specific sequence, plus 2 of any other sequence and the other 3 from one each of the remaining 6 possibilities?

I am working through the probabilities with brute force diagraming and think there must be a better way.

Comment: Forget the $3$ flips: you have $8$ equally likely outcomes A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H. If you want the number of ways to get three of one outcome and the other five from distinct outcomes, i.e. a pattern of results of $1\times 3 + 5 \times 1 + 2\times0=8$ trials, you can do this $\dfrac{8!}{3!^11!^50!^2}\dfrac{8!}{1!5!2!}$ ways - note that the first $8$ is the number of trials and the second $8=1+5+2$ is the number of possible outcomes

Comment: That is a good answer but not what I am looking for.  MY question intended to ask what is the probability of getting in eight three-trial sequences the result AAABCDEF or AAACDEFG or AAADEFGH or any other unique combination of 5 from the 7 BCDEFGH.  The probability for any one of the combinations is the same.

Comment: That is a good answer but not what I am looking for.  MY question intended to ask what is the probability of getting in eight three-trial sequences the result AAABCDEF or AAACDEFG or AAADEFGH or any other unique combination of 5 from the 7 BCDEFGH.  The probability for ANY ONE of the combinations is the same.   P=(8/8)(1/8)(1/8)(7/8)(6/8)(5/8)(4/8)(3/8) = (8!-2!)/(8^8) = (216720-2)/16777216 = 0.012917 or 1/77.415.  What I am trying to derive is a general equation that can be used for any combination of 8 of the 8 sequences ABCDEFGH.  If it has already been done I could save wasted effort.

Comment: If you divide my calculation of $1128960$ by $8^8$ than you get the probability of the patterns you show and the same sort of thing in a different order such as EHDHCBAH, all treated as equally likely.  Is that not what you want?